# Is it possible to get the last four digits of the user credit card with PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the Express Checkout API to handle PayPal payments from a web application. Is it possible to access the last four digits of the user credit card number with this structure? Please note that I can't use another payment flow for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's the whole point of PayPal. You're not supposed to have any access whatsoever to the buyer's financials.
In addition, the buyer could be using a bank account / PayPal balance to fund the transaction.